# How do I say the phrase "Polo is life" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am working on some jerseys for my polo team, and we want to have the words "polo is life" in Latin printed across the back. We don't trust Google translate. For reference, this is equine polo, not water polo. Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to Latin.SE! Please, have a look to [How do I ask a good question?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Polo was popular in the middle ages, so there must have been a Latin word for it. In Greek it was τζυκάνιον, so *tzycanio*? Trapman has *alsulegia equestris*. *Alsulegia* is all over the internet, meaning "hockey" apparently.

Comment: @Figulus By the way, polo is called "horse-ball" in Chinese, so I would make a calque **pila equestris** for it if there is no better extant word

Answer (score -2):

The literal translation is

> Pila equestris est vita

but have been commented to me that "Polo is life" is somehow not supposed to mean the delusional claim that polo is required to have some kind of life, not have some connotations in this way, therefore here is another translation that follows the lines of the comments

> Pila equestris est mea vitae

If follows the claims of "Polo is a big part of who I am", still is lightly delusional like the original title, but not gets to the part of trying to say that if you are unable to practice polo you will die or be a soulless husk, at least for others. Still I don't think that those that are (at least those that say it first) would be enough self aware to not trying to don't trying to put in all people.

Comment: You can't translate idioms word-for-word and hope to preserve the meaning. If you still want to do it that can be a reasonable choice, but it has to be deliberate and explicit.

Comment: @Cairnarvon What is the problem? vita in some expression like this (always with their delusional connotations) basically implies that without the activity or practice in question one is no different that dead. Certainly the literal Pila equestris est vita captures the meaning of the original sentence, and giving that my Spanish-Latin dictionary does not mention another word for lives, I don't understand where can be a problem with the translation.

Comment: "[x] is life" is an idiomatic expression in English. It is not an idiomatic expression in Latin.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Is an Idiom for what? I just read it as being a delusional claim that life is the same as [x] and or is required to life.

Comment: That isn''t what the English means *at all*.

Comment: @cmw What it means then?

Comment: It's a phrase used to indicate devotion to something, but in a lighthearted manner. "Polo is life" means "Polo is a big part of who I am." The connotations are personal: no one is saying that that person *needs* polo to live, or that everyone must have polo to live. There's no delusion at all.

Comment: @cmw As a native Spanish speaker with a very literal way of thought, I consider If you want to say "Polo is a big part of who I am", then "Polo is my life" would be more proper.

Comment: While that may be, English isn't the same as Spanish. Languages are not, and cannot, be purely literal. Even the word "literal" is figurative.